# Java socket crashes client or server?

Tags: java, sockets

OK, so I am completely new to Java sockets, I don't really know the issue and my good friend told me to post this here.

Client:  http://www.pastie.org/4163360

Server:  http://www.pastie.org/4163364

Errors received when I run the client:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at talk.Client.main(Client.java:36)
```

Comment: Is 192.168.1.103 the correct location of your server, and is it accessible from the client machine? The error you are getting indicates that the client cannot contact the server, after trying for a certain amount of time. Can you ping the server from the client? Can you connect to the server using another program, such as telnet?

Comment: The stack trace shows "client can't connect to server".  The *first* thing I'd check for is a firewall.  IMHO...

Comment: your `getNick()` method recursively calls itself when you probably just meant to return the server response.

Comment: in the posted code, `Client.java:36` is a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

Ran your code - had to change the IP of the host, but otherwise all good. Therefore, can confirm this is an IP/Firewall issue. Double check your ipconfig / ifconfig for your IP address. Sorry, but can't comment on questions yet :(